# What is Windows CE 5.0 Build 1400?

Tags: windows-ce

Im development an vb.net application to a Windows Ce 5.0 build 1400 device, but it doesnt work in this device, it only works on Windows Ce 5.0.

What is the "Build 1400"? How can i remove it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a build number generated with the OS.  You can't "remove" it.

If you have two devices, one on which the app work and one on which it doesn't, both running the same OS (CE 5.0 in this case), then it's likely that it's a component issue in the OS.  It could be a driver difference, a P/Invoke library difference, a core OS feature difference, or even an OAL difference.

Without you defining "doesn't work" in more detail, that's as detailed as I can get.  You'll have to use debugging and determine where the app is failing, and then determine what is missing from the OS to cause that failure.

Comment: When i copy my app to the device and run it from the computer, it stops working. When i run it from the device the error is like "0xc00000005".

Comment: How do you copy your app? Are you using the deployment option from Visual Studio, deploying the cab, or simply copying them? Have you installed the .NET or other library required?